# Can football players be penalised for an action against a teammate that is normally a foul if done to the opponent?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

I saw [this video](https://www.facebook.com/BBCMOTD/videos/1963837536965459/) of a player slide tackling his teammate.

What are the rules on players tackling their own teammates like that?

Would it just be to show fair play and kick the ball out to treat the player?

Comment: I've added a late answer which I believe better covers the scenario you've highlighted. The answer you've accepted assumes that the action is bad enough to be a cautionable or sending-off offence.

Comment: @Metro Boomin Yes studro is right, just for an action against teammate which is not excessive enough players can't be penalized, whereas I assumed action is excessive. So, if you could accept the answer of studro I will delete mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(The situation explain in this answer assumes action against a teammate which involve misconduct and wouldn't be only foul. See [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/17537/13485))**

*Can football players be penalised for an action against a teammate that is normally a foul if done to the opponent?*

(Answer is no, for an action against a teammate that is normally a foul if done to the opponent.)

---

<strike>In short yes, laws of the game allows it.</strike>

From [IFAB Laws of The Game](http://www.theifab.com/laws) :

> Law 12 fouls and misconducts (emphasis added)
>
> 3. [DISCIPLINARY ACTION](http://www.theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/disciplinary-action)
>
>    A player who commits a cautionable or sending-off offence, either on or off the field of play, against an opponent, **a team-mate**, a match official or any other person or the Laws of the Game, *is disciplined according to the offence*.
> 4. [RESTART OF PLAY AFTER FOULS AND MISCONDUCT](http://www.theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/restart-of-play-after-fouls-and-misconduct)
>
>    If the ball is in play and a player commits an offence inside the field of play against:
>
>    - a team-mate, substitute, substituted or sent off player, team official or a match official – a direct free kick or penalty kick

From [FAQ of Law 12](http://www.theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/fouls-and-misconduct-faq)

> Q6: Why is an offence against someone who is not an opponent now a direct free kick? Does this include dissent/offensive language?
>
> If, for example, a player strikes a team-mate, substitute, team official or, perhaps even worse, a match official this is serious but only restarting with an IDFK suggested that the offence was not serious so it is now a direct free kick for any offence (directly) against anyone (except an opponent). This does not include dissent/offensive language etc. as this is not a direct/physical offence against a person (see below).
>
> Q7: What is the restart of the referee stops play for dissent/offensive language etc.?
>
> If the referee stops play to penalise a player for dissent/offensive language etc. the restart is an IDFK.

In 1994, Hearts teammates Graeme Hogg and current Hearts manager Craig Levein were sent off for scrapping during a pre-season friendly against Raith Rovers. [Source](https://www.eveningtelegraph.co.uk/fp/video-dundee-players-tackling-sums-teams-poor-start-season/)

**Update**: From the IFAB [Glossary](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/assets/documents/LotG2017/LotG_17_18_EN_Glossary.pdf)

> Penalise
>   To punish, usually by stopping play and awarding a free kick or penalty kick to the opposing team

For Violent Conduct player can be sent-off. (see: [SENDING-OFF OFFENCES](http://www.theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/disciplinary-action))

> VIOLENT CONDUCT
>   Violent conduct is when a player uses or attempts to use excessive force or brutality against an opponent when not challenging for the ball, or against a team-mate, team official, match official, spectator or any other person, regardless of whether contact is made.
>
> In addition, a player who, when not challenging for the ball, deliberately strikes an opponent or any other person on the head or face with the hand or arm, is guilty of violent conduct unless the force used was negligible.

See: *[Newcastle men sent off for fighting each other](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2005/apr/02/newsstory.sport10)*

---

However for the mention case, where [Jack Hendry of Dundee tackles his own team-mate Cammy Kerr](http://www.goal.com/en/news/when-slide-tackles-go-wrong-dundee-defender-takes-out-his/jmqa9sm3iph515hrjm6qlbb75) in a match against Rangers which they lost 4-1, I could not find anything that happened after the incident but I'm sure that [Jack did not get booked](http://www.goal.com/en-om/match/rangers-v-dundee/batrhln2d1kih4ehxu2187eqy).

Comment: This might be a better example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7_ygd9k24w

Comment: Fouls can only be committed against an opponent. See the wording in Law 12 for each offence. However, it is possible to commit misconduct against a team-mate, which is what your quotes are referring to.

Comment: @studro My answer does not state "whether fouls can be committed against an opponent" but only states that "players can be penalised for an action against a teammate"

Comment: But that's not the question. The question is "can players be penalised for an action against a teammate that is normally a foul if done to the opponent"? And the answer is no, unless the action also constituted misconduct.

Comment: None of the examples given here are actions that would result in simply a foul if committed against a teammate. They all involve misconduct.

Answer (score 5):

No, a player cannot be penalised for an action against a teammate that is normally (only) a foul if done to the opponent.

Most free kick offences listed in Law 12 under [direct free kicks](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/direct-free-kick) and [indirect free kicks](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick) that involve physicality against another player (e.g. a careless trip or tackle, or impeding) contain the wording "against an opponent", either directly in the wording of the offence, or in its definition (e.g. playing in a dangerous manner), meaning they cannot be committed against a teammate.

The only exception to this would be if the action was reckless or excessive enough to make it misconduct (i.e. a cautionable or sending-off offence) This free-kick offence is listed in [Law 12 - Fouls and Misconduct, Section 2 - Indirect Free Kick](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick):

> An indirect free kick is awarded if a player:
>
> ...
>
> - commits any other offence, not mentioned in the Laws, for which play is stopped to caution or send off a player

Note that there is no requirement for this offence to be committed against an opponent. This would include committing violent conduct (i.e. using excessive force) or unsporting behaviour (i.e. recklessness) against a teammate.

For these offences, after the offender is either cautioned or sent off, the restart would be upgraded from an indirect free kick offence to a direct free kick offence as per [Law 12 - Fouls and Misconduct, Section 4 - Restart of Play After Fouls and Misconduct](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/restart-of-play-after-fouls-and-misconduct) and Q6 & Q7 of [Law 12 FAQ](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/fouls-and-misconduct-faq).

Comment: The question doesn't say "fouls against an opponent", it says "actions against a teammate that are normally a foul if done to an opponent". I think you've read the conditional in the wrong order.

Comment: The logic could have been clearer, but I believe the conclusion is still correct. I've edited the answer based on your suggestions. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @studro I think you are confused with word "Penalise" and "Caution", what does this mean in your answer "the indirect free kick offence of commits any other offence" and at last I think you meant "Q6".

Comment: I'm not confused by these terms at all. Can you please provide context as to which part of the answer suggests that I am, so it can be corrected? "*commits any other offence, not mentioned in the Laws, for which play is stopped to caution or send off a player*" is the only physical free kick offence in Law 12 (it is listed in Law 12.2) that a player can commit against a teammate, and it requires misconduct to have been committed. I guess Q6 is also applicable, but Q7 clearly highlights that only verbal misconduct against a non-opponent results in an indirect free kick.

Comment: @studro Wouldn't Penalise mean just stopping play and awarding a free kick, whichever that may be.

Comment: @studro Thanks for being patient and explaining me the situation, retracted my wrongly done downvote and upvoted, as soon as OP accepts your answer I will delete mine.

Comment: From the glossary of the LOTG penalise is defined as: "To punish, usually by stopping play and awarding a free kick or penalty kick to the 
opposing team". I would say that a caution or sending-off are also punishments, so cautioning or sending-off a player is also penalising them.

Comment: In response to your second comment, you got in first - so if you incorporate my information into your answer, I'll delete mine. The only reason I left a new answer was because it was so vastly different to yours and it would have been strange to incorporate such a large edit.

Comment: @RamChandraGiri - upon reflection, I think there is enough difference in our answers to warrant leaving mine here.

Comment: @studro Yes that's why I mentioned your answer in mine.